# www class works fine in editor but returns empty www.text and www.error only in UWP build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public string result;
    public Game game;

    IEnumerator Start () 
    {
        WWW www = new WWW ("https://testing.azurewebsites.net/");
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("WWW error is: " + web.error);
        Debug.Log("WWW text is: " + web.text);
    }


    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label (result);
    }
}
```

Both of the log statements return an empty result when the UWP build is run.
However, when running from editor, WWW seems to be working just fine.
I've checked Internet(Client), Internet(Client&Server), Private Networks(Client&Server) in appxmanifest to give app permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have used web.error/web.text. You should replace it with

**www.error and www.text**

```
IEnumerator Start () 
{
    WWW www = new WWW ("https://testing.azurewebsites.net/");
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log("WWW error is: " + www.error);
    Debug.Log("WWW text is: " + www.text);
}
```